# Can ImageMagickNET be used with c#?

Tags: c#, api

I am making an application for editing images. I tried using ImageMagickNET, but can't figure out how to use the API - or if it even works with C#.

Does anybody know ho to use this API or if it works with c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996973/how-to-use-imagemagick-net-in-net-please-for-examples

Comment: @keith Nicholas Thank for the tip, but I've already readit and it does not provide an answer to my question.- whether imagemagicnet can be used with c# or not.

Comment: Have you actually attempted to use it? If so, have you run into issues?

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick.NET appears to be a managed C++ wrapper around the ImageMagick API. As such it should be usable by any .NET language (VB.NET, C#, even IronPython). I don't have experience using it at all but based on what I see in the code in their CodePlex repo I don't see any reason it wouldn't work.