# crop image using imagemagick.net

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I am searching for an example of using imagemagick.net, but nothing found. I have downloaded imagemagick.net and put **ImageMagickNET.dll** as my projects reference. I want to auto crop when I click convert.The code i have tried is giving below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ImageMagickNET;
namespace ImageMagickTest_A
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          MagickNet.Magick.Init();
          MagicNet.Image img = new MagicNet.Image("file.jpg");
          img.Resize(System.Drawing.Size(100,100));
          img.Write("newFile.png");
          MagickNet.Magick.Term();

    }
}
}
```

But I am getting this error "'ImageMagickNET.MagickNet' does not contain a definition for 'Magick'"

Comment: Can you *please* report **which** error you see?!?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I have updated my answer correctly.

Comment: This post is for Crop - but the method you are using is Resize - consider changing this post Title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have used resize method of ImageMagickNET , so please refer below link.. may you can found thing which will help you

[How to use imagemagick.net in .net ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996973/how-to-use-imagemagick-net-in-net-please-for-examples)

Or

```
using System;
using M = MagickNet;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        M.Magick.Init();
        M.Image img = new M.Image("file.jpg");
        img.Resize(new Size(100, 100));
        img.Write("newFile.png");
        MagickNet.Magick.Term();
      }
  }
}
```