# Asp.Net : Convert PDF to Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, pdf

I have a pdf file in a `base64` string format. I need to convert it to an image (any type) to use further in my code.
I have searched SO as well as the web and I have not been successful with anything.

Does anyone have a tried and true method for this?

I can use a third party. I just need a working one!!

Thank you

Comment: You have to render the PDF, using a suitable product or library.

Comment: You have to use 3d party lib for [example](http://blog.apitron.com/2013/06/convert-pdf-to-image-csharp-dotnet-sample.html).

Comment: @Malhotra I'm going to try one of the links you sent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [Apitron PDf Rasterizer](http://apitron.com/Product/pdf-rasterizer)
 to convert my file. It is very simple to use and works great. No missing dlls and clear documentation. However, you do need to purchase it.

Thanks to all for assistance

Answer (score 1):

`base64` is the form of string web friendly representation of byte array. you may convert it to a `byte array` like this:

`byte [] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String (encodedText);`

then you may simple save it to a file:

`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("file.pdf", decodedBytes);`

and then finally [convert pdf to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996973/how-to-use-imagemagick-net-in-net)