# How to compare two images by pixel using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two screenshots. One is **expected**, another one is **actual**. I was looking for a good way to compare those screenshots using C# for my automated selenium tests. I found a few decisions to do that in java but C# doesn't provide a lot. I'd appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageMagick a 3rd party application. It supports command line calls to do image comparison. The following link discusses how to use the command line call:
http://techblog.hotwire.com/2016/05/19/image-comparison-in-automated-testing/

You can also use the nuget package for ImageMagick. This would allow you to embed C# calls to the nuget library in your .NET application. The following stack overflow answer discusses it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235661/2683997

Both of these links assumes that you have been able to do the image capture part already.

Comment: Applitools is another way to do this and is especially nice if you are testing mobile. It is free to a point but most pay for a license. https://applitools.com/

Comment: Thank you, Sean! Will take a look at your approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sikuli with selenium web driver